# Saturated differentially closed field

Tags: model-theory, differential-graded-algebras

What means "saturated" in "saturated differentially closed field" ?

Comment: Presumably saturated in the sense of model theory? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_model

Comment: Yes, but still? The model theoretic material discussed in this wikipedia page is quite abstract. I'm looking for a more concrete explanation, specific to the case of a diff closed field.

Comment: Maybe you should say more precisely what you are interested in. Do you need to prove saturation? Do you want to apply it? What is the characteristic of your differentially closed field?

Comment: By stability, there are saturated dcf of characteristic zero of each uncountable cardinality, and saturated DCF of each positive characteristic of each cardinality $\kappa$ with $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=\kappa$. Since DCF eliminates quantfiers, a $\kappa$-saturated model (for uncountable $\kappa$) is just one which all families of fewer than $\kappa$ constructible sets with the finite intersection property have nonempty intersections. A saturated model is one which is saturated in its own cardinality.